# Box2D collision won't call my own CollisionListener

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I want to use Box2Ds collision detection to check if the player collides with something. So I made a class and implemented the class `CollisionListener` so I can use the methods `beginContact()` to check if the player collides with something. For now I just wanted to print in the console if this methods does even work. It does not. Here is my code:

I made a class `MyCollisionListener` which implements `CollisionListener` like so:

In the class `Play`:

```
// ...
private World world;
private ContactListener contactlistener;

public Play(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -1), true);
    world.setContactListener(contactlistener);
// ...
```

My class `MyContactListener`:

```
public class MyContactListener implements ContactListener {

    public MyContactListener() {}

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        System.out.println("Contact!");
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

For some reason a collison won't call the method `beginContact` in `MyCollisionListener`. Why?

Comment: what makes you think there are contacts?  do you have dynamic bodies?  do they have fixtures?  do you use masking?  is the debugrenderer suggesting you have contacts?

Comment: Of course! I even tried to implement this custom contact listener by setting the listener in another class. world.setContactListener( new ContactListener { put the code here }); And this worked! I don't have a problem with getting the collision or something. The problem I have is, that my class that implements the contact listener won't call it's methods.

Comment: It would help if you were actually using your "MyContactListener" class instead of the "ContactListener" superclass.

Comment: @iforce2d this makes no difference; @Pixell your example ist just an example and lacks the `contactListener=new MyContanctListener()` and you are not passing in an uninitialzied contactListener, right?

Comment: In the Update function of the Contact class, you can see where the beginContact is called from. Put a breakpoint there and see what it does.

Comment: @cfrick why do you say it makes no difference, and then in your very next sentence you suggest what I suggested :D

Comment: @iforce2d having private ContactListener is no problem, it is the interface.  I read your comment as "use private MyContanctListener" and it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iff your code there is not lacking some steps, due to shortening for examples sake, you are passing `null` in as contact listener:

```
private World world;
private ContactListener contactlistener;

public Play(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -1), true);
    contactlistener = new MyContactListener(); // XXX
    world.setContactListener(contactlistener);
```

Comment: thank you a lot! contactlistener = new MyContactListener(); solved the problem! It's been a while since I last implemented a class into my own and completely forgot about that line of code. :D That's what I was looking for. Thanks!